# AWS: how to host ASP.NET MVC + MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net, database, amazon-web-services, model-view-controller

I have an ASP.NET website and a MySQL database to migrate to AWS. My questions are:

1. Is there a managed service for ASP.NET MVC website, just like RDS for database? Or do I have to have a virtual server in EC2 and configure IIS to host this website myself?
2. If the answer to question 1 is "I have to have a virtual server in EC2", then, is it cheaper to increase the EC2 capacity so that it can also host the database, or is it cheapter to host the database in RDS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a service called Elastic Beanstalk, which automates all the provisioning/managing part for you. It supports [ASP.NET](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_NET.quickstart.html), however you'll be charged for the underlying resources (EC2, Elastic load balancer).

If you want something more cost effective, I think you should go for lightsail, if you're not gonna need to scale anytime soon. They are built on t2 instances, and offer a very great price for the package.

Comment: Thank you. Do I install my MySQL on the light sail server and manage myself, or do I host it on RDS?

Comment: you can first put both on the same server. Just in case you need more resources, try using another Lightsail instance, or you want the ability to scale even further, then you should go for RDS, it provides easy management of replicas and multi-AZ deployments.